# How do you properly set a custom profile property in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm trying to save a custom property to an existing user profile in DNN 7, but the profile property is not getting set. I must be understanding something incorrectly.

So, how do you properly set a custom profile property in DNN?

```
UserInfo.Profile.SetProfileProperty("key","value")

// I expect this to return "value", but it's always ""
var value = UserInfo.Profile.GetProfileProperty("key");

// Even if I save it...
ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(UserInfo);

// It always returns ""
var savedValue = UserInfo.Profile.GetProfileProperty("key");
```

Note: I also tried InitialiseProfile but that didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I am accessing a propertyvalue from a property in a module base class I have for a client.

```
public string SomeKey
{
    get
    {
        var ppd = UserInfo.Profile.GetProperty("SomeKey");
        if (ppd.PropertyValue == string.Empty)
        {

            var SomeKeyValue = "blah"
            //update the user's profile property
            UserInfo.Profile.SetProfileProperty("SomeKey", SomeKeyValue);
            //save the user
            DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.UpdateUser(PortalId, UserInfo);
            //retrieve again
            return SomeKey;
        }
        string returnValue = ppd.PropertyValue ??
                             (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ppd.DefaultValue) ? String.Empty : ppd.DefaultValue);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the part I was missing is that I hadn't setup the property/type for users via the UI.

Comment: Ah yeah, I guess I forgot to mention that part too :D